# Draw on any website (without extensions)? Injecting HTML/CSS/JS into any website

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, selenium

I'm following a tutorial to draw shapes on a local webpage using Canvas [Html5 canvas paint](https://dev.opera.com/articles/html5-canvas-painting/).

Thats all well and good, but I'm wanting to replicate the relevant drawing functions/CSS/HTML and "inject" that into any sites source code, for the purposes of being able to draw rectangles/lines on any website. But I'm stuck. Code below:

```
from json import dumps
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

URL = "https://www.google.com/"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.headless = False
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options, executable_path=ChromeDriverManager(log_level=0).install()
    )
driver.get(URL)

# HTML from `<head>` inject style code to existing head style tag
html_head = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("head") # Find the head
html_head_style= html_head.find_element_by_tag_name("style") # Within the head, find the style
inner_html_style = html_head_style.get_property("innerHTML") # Get the styles innerHTML
# Add properties for eventual canvas
new_style = inner_html_style + "#imageView {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;border: 10px solid #000;}"  

# Add canvas style to existing style string as a string
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].innerHTML =" +  dumps(new_style)) #  Inject new_style into the script tag!

# HTML from `<body>`
html_body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") # find the body
location = html_body.location # Get body lcoation
height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight") # Get body height
width = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollWidth") # Get body width

# add canvas to body
new_body = html_body.get_attribute('innerHTML') + f'<canvas id="imageView" width="{width}" height="{height}"></canvas>'
driver.execute_script("document.body.innerHTML =" + dumps(new_body))

# Not working from here on out

js = """
`
<script>/* © 2009 ROBO Design
            * http://www.robodesign.ro
            */
           
           // Keep everything in anonymous function, called on window load.
           if(window.addEventListener) {
           window.addEventListener('load', function () {
             var canvas, context;
           
             // Initialization sequence.
             function init () {
               // Find the canvas element.
               canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
               if (!canvas) {
                 alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
                 return;
               }
           
               if (!canvas.getContext) {
                 alert('Error: no canvas.getConmtext!');
                 return;
               }
           
               // Get the 2D canvas context.
               context = canvas.getContext('2d');
               if (!context) {
                 alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
                 return;
               }
           
               // Attach the mousemove event handler.
               canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_mousemove, false);
             }
           
             // The mousemove event handler.
             var started = false;
             function ev_mousemove (ev) {
               var x, y;
           
               // Get the mouse position relative to the canvas element.
               if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
                 x = ev.layerX;
                 y = ev.layerY;
               } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
                 x = ev.offsetX;
                 y = ev.offsetY;
               }
           
               // The event handler works like a drawing pencil which tracks the mouse 
               // movements. We start drawing a path made up of lines.
               if (!started) {
                 context.beginPath();
                 context.moveTo(x, y);
                 started = true;
               } else {
                 context.lineTo(x, y);
                 context.stroke();
               }
             }
           
             init();
           }, false); }
           
           // vim:set spell spl=en fo=wan1croql tw=80 ts=2 sw=2 sts=2 sta et ai cin fenc=utf-8 ff=unix:
           </script>
`
"""


# Tried the below code via debugger no luck
'''
driver.execute_script("document.body.innerHTML += " + dumps(js))
driver.execute_script("debugger;")
driver.refresh()
'''
```

I've been using [google](https://google.com) as my test site. Now I have managed to "inject" a canvas that I can see via the new black borders around google successfully!

but I fall apart at the javascript. I realized I can't inject my own premade JS files, so I tried injecting js functions directly between script tags (as in the code 'js' variable). Then I realized JS won't run if its injected, it needs to be there at page load aka refresh, but injected files are lost on refresh. Then I tried using breakpoints and debugging to "save and refresh" my JS on the page - still no luck.I've also tried bookmarklets. This is day 3 of trial and error!

Please help I feel like this can be accomplished, just need smarter folks insight

Comment: you could wrap your draw code in a function then call the function from the console

Comment: uhm you ask how to XSS google?

Comment: @reece could you perhaps answer in code as I’m not sure how that solves my issue.

Comment: @toHo I’m new to this stuff, do you have any alternatives?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@opticMan generally "good guys" in browsers world do everything possible to prohibit from executing 3rd party scripts on their sites. It is something known as XSS, you can read more [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=xss)

If you want to manipulate any website you want, you would need to to it with a browser extension. If just want to learn and experiment try injecting code to your own website you control (maybe simple development server using nodejs and express).

Comment: thanks @toHo I figured as much. One other way I’m thinking of trying is to insert an invisible iframe that size of the page into the site, that links to a local html file with all the drawing functions and css preloaded. I need to figure out a way that i can still scroll on the website (which scrolls the iframe canvas at the same time) and draw on the iframe. Sounds like a pipe dream though

Comment: good luck! if there is a will there is a way, dont give up easy :D